# Is it technically correct to say variables and constants are objects of data types?

Tags: c++, c

Can one say **Variables and constants are objects of data types** ?

I wonder what would be the proper explanation for this

```
int a;

float f;
```

Here, Can we say `a` is an object of type `int` and `f` is an object of type `float`?

Comment: In C++ a variable is either a reference or an object. A reference is not an object.

Comment: What do you mean by "constants"? `42`, for example is a constant, and is *not* an object. `const` and "constant", despite the similarity of their names, are not the same thing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Yes

Per paragraph §1.8, both `a` and `b` are objects of their corresponding types.

> <sup>1</sup> **An object is a region of storage.** [Note: A function is not an object,
>   regardless of whether or not it occupies storage in the way that
>   objects do. —end note ] An object is created by a definition (3.1), by
>   a new-expression (5.3.4) or by the implementation (12.2) when needed.
>   The properties of an object are determined when the object is created.
>   An object can have a name (Clause 3). An object has a storage duration
>   (3.7) which influences its lifetime (3.8). An object has a type (3.9).
>   **The term object type refers to the type with which the object is
>   created**.
>
> [intro.object]

and those variables fit in the above quoted definition.

Answer (score 6):

`a` and `f` are objects of type `int` and type `float`, respectively. Yes, that contradicts what @Patashu says, and that's because we're using different definitions of "object".

@Patashu uses the definition from object-oriented programming: an object is a thing with methods, etc. And that's perfectly fine.

However, C++ is a multi-paradigm language -- it supports more than one programming model. The C++ language definition uses the word "object" in the broader sense that compiler writers use: an object is a region of storage with various operations that can be performed on that storage. The operations are defined by the object's type. There's a well-defined set of operations that can be applied to an object of type `int`, so when you know that you're dealing with an `int` you and the compiler know what things you can do with it and, by implication, what things you can't do with it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say yes. A *data object* is simply a region of storage that contains a value or a group of values. Both `int a` and `float f` agree with this definition. If we want to see the differences between those and the "traditional" objects in object oriented languages, we should show the concept of *data type*, which helps the compiler allocate storage for that data object, and interpret its memory values when it is accessed.

Each data object in C++ must have a data type (identifiers for data objects and data types are established in the variable/constant *declaration*). In the classification of data types is where we see that `int a;` and `Object a;` are not "quite the same":

`int` and `float` are *basic* data types, in the sense that they are provided by the language. The `Object` type in this example would be a `derived` type because it is created from basic types.

Data types can be classified in other, often overlapping, groups: For example, one can say that `Object` is a *user-defined* type; and that `int` is a *scalar* type, because it represents a single data value.

Answer (score 0):

## No

(or rather "arguably not")

Ad *"Variables and constants are objects of data types"*:

Although you can find the phrase "object of type" in the C++ Standard (like "object of type T" [basic.def.odr]/5) and the C Standard (e.g. "object of type wchar_t" 3.7.3), one could argue about the use of the term "variable" in your example, at least in C++:

[basic]/6

> A variable is introduced by the declaration of a reference other than a non-static data member or of an object. The variable’s name denotes the reference or object.

So, `int answer = 42; int& deepthought = answer;` introduces:

- an object of type `int`
- a variable, name `answer`, referring to the object above
- a variable, name `deepthought`, referring to the same object

But a reference AFAIK is not an object (does not have to be) -- so one could argue that variables are not necessarily objects. Of course, they're not identical, e.g. dynamic memory allocation.

---

Ad *"a is object of datatype int and f an object of type float"*

AFAIK that complies to the Standard, although to be more precise, one would have to include something like "denotes", e.g. "`a` denotes an object of datatype int".

But I think there's no ambiguity, therefore I consider it OK.

Comment: N.B. in C, the term "constant" has a different meaning as in C++. Constants in C are literals in C++. Whatever name you give it, non-string constants/literals are rvalues, which probably disqualifies them as objects (you can't take an address of them, you can't assign to them, ergo it isn't required that they actually occupy storage).